# I want to generate sigHex from sign in rust

Tags: subxt

This is the polkadotjs code:

```
const { Keyring } = require('@polkadot/keyring');

const seeds = "caution juice atom organ advance problem want pledge someone senior holiday very";
const keyring = new Keyring();
const pair = keyring.addFromUri(seeds);
const sig = pair.sign(pair.address);
const sigHex = '0x' + Buffer.from(sig).toString('hex');
```

I want to convert it into rust using subxt. Here is my code so far:

```
use sp_core::{
    sr25519,
    Pair,
};
use sp_keyring::AccountKeyring;

use subxt::{
    Client,
    DefaultConfig,
    PairSigner,
    SubstrateExtrinsicParams, extrinsic::Signer,
};

fn get_from_seed(seed: &str) -> sr25519::Pair {
    sr25519::Pair::from_string(&format!("//{}", seed), None)
        .expect("static values are valid; qed")
}

pub fn pair_signer(pair: sr25519::Pair) -> PairSigner<DefaultConfig, sr25519::Pair> {
    PairSigner::new(pair)
}


fn main() {
    let pair = get_from_seed("caution juice atom organ advance problem want pledge someone senior holiday very");
    let pairsigner = pair_signer(pair);
    let sig = pairsigner.sign(pairsigner.address());
    
}
```

But I am unable to convert it into hex.
sign() takes &[u8], mismatched types expected reference `&[u8]` found enum `MultiAddress<AccountId32, u32>`

Answer (score 1):

Seems solved it:

```
use sp_core::{
    sr25519,
    ed25519,
    Pair,
};
use sp_keyring::AccountKeyring;
use sp_runtime::MultiSignature;

use subxt::{
    Client,
    DefaultConfig,
    PairSigner,
    SubstrateExtrinsicParams, extrinsic::Signer,
};

fn get_from_seed(seed: &str) -> ed25519::Pair {
    ed25519::Pair::from_string(&format!("{}", seed), None)
        .expect("static values are valid; qed")
}

pub fn pair_signer(pair: ed25519::Pair) -> PairSigner<DefaultConfig, ed25519::Pair> {
    PairSigner::new(pair)
}


fn main() {
    let pair = get_from_seed("caution juice atom organ advance problem want pledge someone senior holiday very");
    let pairsigner = pair_signer(pair);
    println!("{}", pairsigner.account_id());
    let sig = pairsigner.sign(format!("{}", pairsigner.account_id()).as_bytes());
    if let MultiSignature::Ed25519(x) = sig.clone() {
        println!("0x{:?}", x);
    }
    
    
}
```